# How change editor color for xml in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, odoo, editor

I use Eclipse and Odoo, how change editor for *.xml* in Eclipse *luna*.

After open *xml* file get text as following

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNXKJ.jpg

I need some tags display in color.

Comment: can you take a picture of you preference window

Comment: @Charif http://imgur.com/a/8Mtjb

Comment: if you are using eclipse for odoo i recommand pycharm too it's greate easy tool too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with following steps:

**Step 1** - Go to Help menu 
**Step 2** - Click on **"Install New Software"**
**Step 3** - From the drop down **"Work With"**, select **"--All available sites--"**
        As soon as you will select this option, It will try to load the 
        available options under it.
**Step 4** - Try to find the option as **"Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development"** and expand it.
**Step 5** - From these expanded options find **"Eclipse XML Editors..."** and install it.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing XML tools you need to install them :

[image: Eclipse preferences]
try to install them from

Help ---> install new Software

search for XML

or download an eclipse IDE version for web developement.

Comment: Can you share link for download?

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse: Right click on the xml > Open With > Other > Select Java Editor > Check mark "Use it for all '*xml' files. > OK

Now your java editor is your xml editor, have fun!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y01py.png)